# Estender a classe do PHPWord no CI - class not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou tentando colocar a library do PHPWord no codeigniter, para isso baixei o PHPWord e extraí a pasta PHPWord e o arquivo PhpWord.php para a pasta third_party do CI. Após isto criei na pasta libraries um arquivo com o nome `word.php` que estenderia as funcionalidades dos PhpWord.php.

Até aí tudo certo, mas quando chamo a library `Word.php` no meu controller recebo o seguinte erro

> Class PHPWORD not found in (caminho-do-arquivo/Word.php).

Já ouvi dizer que antes de fazer isso eu precisaria chamar o arquivo autoloader, tentei dessa forma também e não obtive sucesso, alguém saber me ajudar ?

Segue o código do arquivo `Word.PHP`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPWord.php"; 

    class Word extends PHPWord { 
        public function __construct() { 
            parent::__construct(); 
        } 
}
```

Eu segui uma parte neste tutorial que encontrei na internet :

http://www.ahowto.net/php/creating-ms-word-document-using-codeigniter-and-phpword/

Comment: Qual a versão do phpword você está utilizando ?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 0.12.0 stable.
peguei ela do github : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema que você está tendo é basicamente chamando um arquivo que não existe.

O PHPWord sofreu diversas alterações desde a data que esse tutorial foi criado (2012). Ele começou a suportar PSR-0 para autoload e a utilizar Namespaces, o que modificou em muito (para melhor) a arquitetura do projeto. Infelizmente o Codeigniter "parou" no tempo e não possui suporte a nada disso.

Você tem duas opções:

1. Utilizar o autoloader da versão mais recente e incluir também o Namespace (requer pelo menos PHP 5.3). Se atente para os caminhos dos arquivo, se realmente existem, etc...

   ```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

       require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPWord/autoload.php";

       class Word extends PHPOffice\PHPWord { 
           public function __construct() { 
               parent::__construct(); 
           } 
   }
   ```
2. Utilizar uma versão mais antiga com a estrutura da biblioteca parecida com a do tutorial que você está utilizando (no caso a 0.8.1). A estrutura de pastas é a mesma:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/0.8.1/Classes

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**PS.:** Procure se atualizar com o que há de novo no PHP antes de sair desenvolvendo. Sinto lhe dizer mas você já está gerando código obsoleto caso esteja trabalhando em um novo projeto com Codeigniter.

Um norte de como começar bem é o [PHP: Do Jeito Certo](http://br.phptherightway.com/).

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão @gmsantos, vou testar assim que possível, e agradeço também pela dica, vou dar uma olhada no link que voce me recomendou.

Comment: @ThECoDeR caso a resposta seja útil, você pode marcar como resposta para sua pergunta ou votar positivamente. Saiba mais fazendo um [tour] e bem vindo ao Stack Overflow!

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado pela ajuda.